# What's best Uwp alternative to Xamarin Forms' `FlexLayout`

Tags: uwp, uno-platform

I'm looking for a `FlexLayout` kind of control for Uwp, with support for Uno platform.
Where should I start looking at?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Community Toolkit offers WrapPanel and WrapLayout, while not being the exact equivalent of FlexLayout, they do cover a lot of scenarios, especially for a collection of elements. They allow for stacks of elements and automatically go on the next row/column when required.

Reference: [WrapLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/layout/wraplayout) and [WrapPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wrappanel)

Uno's support of Windows Community Toolkit is [here](https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.WindowsCommunityToolkit)
and available on nuget.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I've translated Xamarin.Forms.FlexLayout (including bugs) to Uno and have submitted it to as a [pull request to the Windows Community Toolkit team](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/pull/3485). That being said, they asked me to rename it `FlexPanel` and asked for changes that requires usage with the current dev version of WCT.  I don't have time at the moment to implement everything they've asked, so it's going to be a while before it will make it through the WCT review process.

If you want an implementation that doesn't require too much complexity to integrate into your projects, I have a [working repo that I'm actively maintaining](https://bitbucket.org/baskren/p42.uno.controls/src/dev/) you are welcome to try.  Alternatively, I also still have the [development repo](https://github.com/baskren/FlexLayoutDev) I used for the bulk of the translation and testing before trying to integrate into the WCT codebase.  Again, you're welcome to try.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, there's no direct equivalent on UWP. But it should be possible to simply port the [FlexLayout's code](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/5.0.0/Xamarin.Forms.Core/FlexLayout.cs) to UWP/WinUI/Uno.

On WinUI, there's a new thing called [`ItemsRepeater`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/items-repeater) where you have a lot of flexibility for the layout of items, but it's not supported *yet* on Uno.  You may want to follow its [experimental Pull Request](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/pull/3553).